# Hibernate : GenericGenerator Details

Tags: java, hibernate

I am learning Hibernate ....

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="foreign")
@GenericGenerator(name="foreign", strategy="foreign", parameters={
        @Parameter(name="property" ,value="company")
})
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

In the above code i understand most of the things except these lines

```
parameters={
        @Parameter(name="property" ,value="company")
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For every GenericGenerator, you can pass a list of key/value (parameters) regarding your strategy.

A GenericGenerator using the strategy "foreign" expects one **parameter** called *"property"* and the expected **value** is an *entity name*. This means your entity's ID will be the same as the linked entity.

For example:

**Author entity**:

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="authors")  
public class Author {  

    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue  
    private Integer id;  

    private String name;  

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="author", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
    private Biography biography;      
}
```

**Biography entity**:

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="biographies")  
public class Biography {  

    @Id  
    @Column(name="id")  
    @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")  
    @GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign",   
    parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="author"))  
    private Integer id;  

    @OneToOne  
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn  
    private Author author;  
}
```

In that case, every Biography ID will have the same ID as the Author's ID.